# Cannot send headers; headers already sent

Tags: shipping, event-observer, invoice

I have been trying to create an Observer which automatically creates shipping whenever an invoice has been created by hooking into the:

```
sales_order_invoice_register_handler
```

Event, whenever I create an invoice my observer fires but I get a warning `"Cannot create empty shipment"`

I've checked the var/report and can see

```
Cannot send headers; headers already sent
```

I am not sure what is the cause of this but have spent hours trying to figure out the cause...

Here is my Observer.php code

```
<?php

class MyModule_SendShipment_Model_Observer
{

        public function salesOrderShipmentCreate($observer)
        {
//            echo("My Observer is Observing");
//            die();

            $itemsQty = array();
            $comment = null;
            $email = true;
            $includeComment = false;

            $order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderIncrementId);
            if ($order->canShip()){

                $itemsQty = array();
                foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
                    $itemsQty[$item->getId()] = $item->getQtyOrdered();
                }

                $shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);

            }


            if ($order->canShip() && $shipment){
                $shipment->register();
                $shipment->addComment($comment, $email && $includeComment);
                if ($email) {
                    $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
                }
                $shipment->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
                try {
                    $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
                        ->addObject($shipment)
                        ->addObject($shipment->getOrder())
                        ->save();
                    $shipment->sendEmail($email, ($includeComment ? $comment : ''));
                } catch (Mage_Core_Exception $e) {
                    Mage::logException($e);
                }
                echo $shipment->getIncrementId();
            }


        }

}
```

If anyone can help I'd be very grateful...

Comment: You should paste the entire contents of `Observer.php` - make sure there aren't things being echoed at the top of the file or anything.

Comment: If you remove the observer, do you still see the headers error in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line `var_dump( $e->getMessage());` will print the result to the browser and give the error **Cannot send headers; headers already sent**.

You should change this line to:

```
 Mage::logException($e);
```

That being said the error **Cannot create empty shipment** is what is causing the exception in the first place. It's hard to debug from without seeing the full observer you have, but initally I can see that you are calling this line twice in your code, once outside your check for if the order is not able to be shipped:

```
$shipment = $order->prepareShipment($itemsQty);
```

So I would remove the second one of the above line and change this line from :

```
if ($shipment) {
```

to:

```
if ($order->canShip() && $shipment) {
```

Comment: Thankyou, I will give that a try now and let you know...

Comment: The error has gone but still not shipment being generated :(